# Programmatically instantiate components in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Is it possible to programmatically create an component in aurelia and then somehow bind it to a tag of that type in the view. For example something like a simple tree view, see the comments in the HTML templates below.

---

**tree-view.ts**

```
import {TreeNode} from "./tree-node";

export class TreeView<T> {
    private _rootNodes: TreeNode<T>[] = [];

    get rootNodes(): TreeNode<T>[] {
        return this._rootNodes;
    }

    public addRootNode(node: TreeNode<T>) {
        this._rootNodes.push(node);
    }
}
```

**tree-node.ts**

```
export class TreeNode<T> {

    private _value: T;
    private _name: string;
    private _children: TreeNode<T>[] = [];

    get value(): T {
        return this._value;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    get children(): TreeNode<T>[] {
        return this._children;
    }

    public addChild(child: TreeNode<T>): void {
        this._children.push(child);
    }

    constructor(name: string, value: T) {
        this._name = name;
        this._value = value;
    }
}
```

**tree-view.html**

```
<template>
    <!-- Something like this is the intend -->
    <tree-node repeat.for="node of rootNodes"></tree-node>
</template>
```

**tree-node.html**

```
<template>
    <div>${name}</div>

    <div class='childNodes'>
        <!-- Something like this is the intend -->
        <tree-node repeat.for="node of children"></tree-node>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You could add it to the DOM and call `enhance` on it, but in general if you are trying to dynamically add things to the DOM you know where they are going to go so I suggest using the `compose` custom element

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't do this using custom-element declaration. I don't know if there's a way to set the custom-element's view-model. You can use `compose` as a workaround.

**Tree-view.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="./tree-node"></require>

    <!-- Something like this is the intend -->
    <compose repeat.for="node of rootNodes" view="./tree-node.html" view-model.bind="node"></compose>
</template>
```

**Tree-node.html**

```
<template>
    <div>${name}</div>

    <div class='childNodes' style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <!-- Something like this is the intend -->
        <compose repeat.for="node of children" view="./tree-node.html" view-model.bind="node"></compose>
    </div>
</template>
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=95b8892918d7e5a7aadf0ac7eb28124d

Another solution (and better in my opinion) is exposing `name` and `child` as bindable properties:

```
export class TreeNode {
    @bindable value;
    @bindable name;
    @bindable children = [];
}
```

In this way, you would be able to do something like this:

```
<tree-node repeat.for="node of rootNodes" name.bind="node.name" value.bind="node.value" children.bind="node.children"></tree-node>
```

This is a little bit more verbose but faster. In the mean time, I'll see if there's a way to set the custom-element's view-model.

Comment: I don't know how the bindable solution copes with deep nested objects, as the children might contain children and so on. If I use it as a bindable property doesn't that imply that the whole object must be serialized to a string to be usable as a html property?

Comment: No, it doesn't! When you use `property.bind` the framework will make the variable assignment. There's no string serialisation involved.

Comment: Have to look into that, but is there a way to bind the element itself to the instance created? Like: <tree-node repeat.for="node of rootNodes" bind="node"></tree-node>

Comment: I don't think so, and I also don't think it would make sense because when you do <tree-node></tree-node> the VM is instantiated. Replacing this instance for another instance wouldn't make much sense for me... But I'm not sure about this, I'll try to task the team to get an official answer

Comment: This would be great, thanks. It would be interesting if there is any "code-first" approach for components available.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is a core functionality of Aurelia.
Please see [http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components#creating-a-component](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components)

By creating a component you can now use that component in any html as `<mycomponent></mycomponent>`

Components can contain other components.

Comment: I guess you mean something different. I am searching a way of programmatically instantiating a component (new MyComponent()) and the in the view link the tag <mycomponent> to the created instance. Primarily because the components may have a complex data model.